# How can I capture the output of an external program that returns a non-zero exit code?

Tags: julia

Prior to Julia 0.5, I could run

```
diff = readlines(`diff $oldfile $newfile`)
```

and get the diff between the files.

Now Julia throws an exception because diff returns exit code 1, so I no longer get the output assigned to my variable.

What is the intended way of working around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
diff = readlines(Cmd(`diff $oldfile $newfile`, ignorestatus=true))
```

Comment: Apparently I can also do ``diff = readlines(ignorestatus(`diff $oldfile $newfile`))`` which is slightly less ugly.